# Error : GetFilter cannot open stream of object because filter

Tags: php, pdf, codeigniter-3, fpdf

I am getting this error while using FPDM library for binding data in Editable PDF.

I want to bind this data to PDF. PDF has no issue at all. 
This code creates PDF for the first instance of Array only.

When I am combining this code to Codeigniter, I am getting an error.

You can see code of mine As below and suggest solution for that one.

Code

```
<?php

/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

require('fpdm.php');



    $fields[0] = array( 'app_no'    => '43922230',
         'name1' => 'pravinkumar R',
         'name2'    => 'ramabhai patel',
         'address1'   => '25127 samani society',
         'branch_code'   => '300047',
         'area'   => 'chansma',
         'city'   => 'chansma',
         'pin'   => '384220',
         'email'   => '0',
         'phone'   => '9033381560',
         'pan'   => 'AEOEPP0147F',
         'pan2'   => 'AEOEPP0147F',
         'client_id1' => 'IN30154945999461',
         'NSDL'    => '1',
         'CDSL'   => '0',
         'personal'   => '1',
         'huf'    => '0',
         'date'   => '12-01-2018',
         'bank_name2'    => 'AXIS BANK,CHANSMA',
         'bank_acco_no1' => '50100020583815',
         'amount_block2'    => '13150',
         'client_id2'   => 'IN30154945999461',
         'app_no2'   => '43922230',
         'bank_no3'    => '50100020583815',
         'bank_name' => 'AXIS BANK,CHANSMA',
         'amount_words'    => 'thirteen thousand one hundred fifty only',
         'amount_blocked'   => '13150',
         'share'   => '50',


         'amount_block3'    => '13150',
         'share2' => '50',
         'email2'    => ' ',
         'phone2'   => '9033381560',
         'client_name'   => 'ramabhai patel',
         'app_no3'    => '43922230',
         'bank_name3' => 'AXIS BANK,CHANSMA',
         'name2'    => 'ramabhai patel',
         'bank_acco_no2'   => '50100020583815',
         'name3'   => 'name3');


    $fields[1] = array( 'app_no'    => '43922230',
         'name1' => 'pravinkumar R',
         'name2'    => 'ramabhai patel',
         'address1'   => '25127 samani society',
         'branch_code'   => '300047',
         'area'   => 'chansma',
         'city'   => 'chansma',
         'pin'   => '384220',
         'email'   => '0',
         'phone'   => '9033381560',
         'pan'   => 'AEOEPP0147F',
         'pan2'   => 'AEOEPP0147F',
         'client_id1' => 'IN30154945999461',
         'NSDL'    => '1',
         'CDSL'   => '0',
         'personal'   => '1',
         'huf'    => '0',
         'date'   => '12-01-2018',
         'bank_name2'    => 'AXIS BANK,CHANSMA',
         'bank_acco_no1' => '50100020583815',
         'amount_block2'    => '13150',
         'client_id2'   => 'IN30154945999461',
         'app_no2'   => '43922230',
         'bank_no3'    => '50100020583815',
         'bank_name' => 'AXIS BANK,CHANSMA',
         'amount_words'    => 'thirteen thousand one hundred fifty only',
         'amount_blocked'   => '13150',
         'share'   => '50',


         'amount_block3'    => '13150',
         'share2' => '50',
         'email2'    => ' ',
         'phone2'   => '9033381560',
         'client_name'   => 'ramabhai patel',
         'app_no3'    => '43922230',
         'bank_name3' => 'AXIS BANK,CHANSMA',
         'name2'    => 'ramabhai patel',
         'bank_acco_no2'   => '50100020583815',
         'name3'   => 'name3');

    //print_r($fields);
    $dir = "client_pdf/";
    $i=1;
    foreach($fields as $key => $val){

        $pdfName = "sample_".$i.".pdf";
        //echo $pdfName."<br>";
        $pdf = new FPDM('pdf/newgen.pdf');
        $pdf->Load($val, true); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
        $pdf->Merge();
        $pdf->Output('group_pdf/pdf.pdf','F');
        $i++;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in a foreach cycle only the first iteration worked.
I found out that, because in the FPDM class constructor the filters are loaded with a `require_once` statement, after the first iteration they are not loaded anymore.

My solution was to instantiate the FPDM class just once before the cycle.
Inside cycle just `Load()`, `Merge()` and `Output()`.

There's no need to instantiate more than once unless you need to change the template, the `Load()` method will substitute all the fields and then you can `Merge()` safely.
It worked for me.

```
$pdf = new FPDM('pdf/newgen.pdf');
foreach($fields as $key => $val){
    $pdfName = "sample_".$i.".pdf";
    $pdf->Load($val, true); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
    $pdf->Merge();
    $pdf->Output('group_pdf/pdf.pdf','F');
    $i++;
}
```